# which images load the android device at the time of installation?

Tags: android

I am placing 20 images in hdpi folder, 20 images in mdpi folder and 20 images in ldpi folder, all are same images but different resolutions . I am placing my app in android market. One user install my app in his normal android device through market, My question is total 60 images download the device or only 20 images(mdpi) download the device at the time of install the app.Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is archived in a single file (.APK) so all devices, regardless of density, will receive all of the images (all 60, in this case).

Answer (score 0):

your compiled .apk is what is uploaded to the play store, and the compiled .apk contains **all** of your applications resources...so in short yes it is all 60